# My cake is moist but crumbly

Tags: cake, texture

I have always used this recipe and this turns out really soft and moist, but also crumbly. How can I fix it?

Here are the ingredients:

- 1 1/2 cups (3 sticks) unsalted butter, room temperature, plus more for pans
- 3/4 cup Dutch-process cocoa powder, sifted, plus more for pans
- 3/4 cup hot water
- 3/4 cup sour cream
- 3 cups cake flour, (not self-rising), sifted
- 1 teaspoon baking soda
- 1/2 teaspoon salt
- 2 1/4 cups sugar
- 4 large eggs
- 1 tablespoon pure vanilla extract

I haven't used up all the batter yet, so I can do changes if required. Please help!

Comment: how did you bake it? what temperature? what type of oven / pan? Can you [edit] the question to add more details?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Method is important, how do you make the batter? Please edit with details.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing part of the water and/or cream with more egg should do the trick, as when eggs are headed, they firm up and act as a binding element, fixing the crumblyness of your cake.